# Example for Coordinate Transformation Suite (abridged CTS) Android

Tags: android

I want to transform my EPSG:25833 coordinates to google WGS84 at my android app.
After long time searching i found the Coordinate Transformation Suite (abridged CTS) library.

Has anybody a working example

if i try the example from orbisgis i get the error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" on path:

```
   CRSFactory cRSFactory = new CRSFactory();

    // Add the appropriate registry to the CRSFactory's registry manager. Here the EPSG registry is used.
    RegistryManager registryManager = cRSFactory.getRegistryManager();
    registryManager.addRegistry(new EPSGRegistry());

    // CTS will read the EPSG registry seeking the 4326 code, when it finds it,
    // it will create a CoordinateReferenceSystem using the parameters found in the registry.
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = cRSFactory.getCRS("EPSG:25833");
  //  CoordinateReferenceSystem crs2 = cRSFactory.getCRS("EPSG:4326");


    double[] coord = new double[2];
    coord[0] = 54.321;
    coord[1] = 9.876;


    CoordinateReferenceSystem  crs1 = cRSFactory.getCRS("EPSG:4326");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem  crs2 = cRSFactory.getCRS("EPSG:25832");
    GeodeticCRS sourceGCRS = (GeodeticCRS) crs;
    GeodeticCRS targetGCRS = (GeodeticCRS) crs2;
    List<CoordinateOperation> coortzdOps = CoordinateOperationFactory.createCoordinateOperations(sourceGCRS,targetGCRS);
    if (coortzdOps.size() != 0) {
        for (CoordinateOperation op : coortzdOps) {
            double[] dd  = op.transform(coord);
            for (int i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Error log:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory;
>                             at org.cts.registry.RegistryManager.(RegistryManager.java:40)
>                             at org.cts.CRSFactory.(CRSFactory.java:68)
>                             at com..transform.trans(transform.java:169)
>                             at com..MapGoogle.onMapReady(MapGoogle.java:75)
>                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
>                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzp$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>                             at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
>                             at xz.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
>                             at maps.ad.u$5.run(Unknown Source)
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5683)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
>                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" on path: D

Comment: CTS https://github.com/orbisgis/cts/wiki is used in OpenJUMP and Orbis GIS. Working examples about using the library can be found from the source code of those two open source projects but maybe you are after examples about using CTS on Android.

Comment: @user30184 i try to use the orbisgis example but i get the error that he can't find a class

Comment: Do you mean that the message that says that org.slf4j.LoggerFactory can't be found from your path is somehow invalid?

Comment: @user30184 i imported org.cts.CRSFactory from the lib. but the exception i get is from org.slf4j.Loggerfactory

Comment: I believe that your problem in not a GIS one but about running Java code on Android and belong to another forum. OrbisGIS developers most probably run Java on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.slf4j.org/android/.

Comment: @SeanBarbeau Thanks. It helps. my library needed an lib from slf4j. Thanks all for help